# How to update PowerShell modules via PowerShell runbook?

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to automate the sentinel alerts. It requires Az.Accounts and Az.securityInsights modules as pre-requisites. I'm running PowerShell scripts via automation account.

The PowerShell runbook contains default versions of Az.Accounts and Az.SecurityInsights modules. I need to update these modules to the latest version for PowerShell 5.1 version.

I have used the below command but facing error:

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.Accounts | Update-Module
```

Error:

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): "A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with NuGet-based repositories. The NuGet provider must be available in 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or 'C:\Users\Client\AppData\Roaming\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. You can also install the NuGet provider by running 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install and import the NuGet provider now?"

How can I update the versions of these modules via PowerShell script?

```
Az.Accounts (>2.11 version)
Az.SecurityInsights (3.0.1 version)
```

### Update

As per suggestions given by answerers, I used this script but still facing below error:

```
# Install the latest version of the NuGet provider
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion '2.8.5.201' -Force 

# Update the Az.Accounts module
Update-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force

# Update the Az.SecurityInsights module
 Update-Module -Name Az.SecurityInsights -Force

# Import the updated modules
 Import-Module Az.Accounts
 Import-Module Az.SecurityInsights
```

Error:

> No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.

Comment: Pro tip: When pasting in large chunks of error or stack trace, readability is harmed greatly if they are not formatted. Please use quote blocks or code blocks to present them as different to your own "voice", so that questions are easier to understand. Please see [the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75711631/revisions) in this case to see the fixes that were applied to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too received same errors when I tried your command and other answer's command as below:

[image]

[image]

To update modules try to follow below steps and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-azure-modules):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Another way of doing that is:

[image]

By following below steps you can update your packages in Runbook. AFAIK, using commands you will get errors as have got. So I suggest you to  try to follow traditional and documented way like above process.

Comment: Hi Rithwik.. I'm able to update the modules via azure portal. But, since I'm automating using powershell script, want to update the existing modules via powershell script itself. But Facing issue with NuGet Module

Comment: I would suggest you to do only this part using Portal.

Comment: ok.. Edited the above post ..

Comment: Hi Rithwik .. Via portal .. able to update the modules.. Thanks a lot for ur suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use the '-Force' option:

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az.Accounts | Update-Module -Force
```

If that doesn't work, update the NuGet version then try again:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```